# JS Array Find and Replace?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a regular expression happening that searching for all the capitals in a document. It gathers them and puts them into an array no problem.

The issue I am having is I want to replace the items in that array to include a span around each item that was captured in the array and then display the updated result. I've tried a variety of things.

I am at a complete loss. Any help is appreciated. Here was my last attempt

```
var allCaps = new RegExp(/(?:[A-Z]{2,30})/g);
    var capsArray = [];
    var capsFound;

    while (capsFound = allCaps.exec(searchInput)) {
        capsArray.push(capsFound[0]);
    }


    //for(var x = 0; x < capsArray.length; x++){

            //var test = ;
            capsArray.splice(0, '<span style="color:green">'+ capsArray +'</span>');

    //}
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `capsFound === allCaps.exec(searchInput)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the results in an array? If not, you can wrap all caps in a str using a modified regex:

```
str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '<span>$1</span>')
```

example:

`'A--B--C'` becomes `'<span>A</span>---<span>B</span>---<span>C</span>'`

if the array is needed for whatever reason:

```
str.split(/[^A-Z]+/g).map(x => `<span>${x}</span>`)
```

example:

`'A--B--C'` becomes `['<span>A</span>', '<span>B</span>', '<span>C</span>']`

Comment: there's also the version of `.replace` that takes a callback function

Answer (score 5):

You can't convert an entire array's elements like that using `splice` - you can use `.map` instead:

```
capsArray = capsArray.map(c => '<span style="color:green">' + c + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Heres my final solution for anyone else that gets lost along the way

```
var allCaps = new RegExp(/(?:[A-Z]{2,30})/g);
var capsArray = [];
var capsFound;

while (capsFound = allCaps.exec(searchInput)) {
    capsArray.push(capsFound[0]);
}

if(capsArray.length > 0){
    resultsLog.innerHTML += "<br><span class='warning'>So many capitals</span><br>";
    searchInput = document.getElementById('findAllErrors').innerHTML;
    searchInput = searchInput.replace(/([A-Z]{3,30})/g, '<span style="background-color:green">$1</span>');
    document.getElementById('findAllErrors').innerHTML = searchInput;
}
else {
    resultsLog.innerHTML += "";
}
```